# Custom activity theme with default dialog theme

Tags: android, dialog, styles, themes

I'm trying to display an AlertDialog with the default AppCompat theme, meanwhile the main activity is having a custom theme. My problem is that the AlertDialog displayed seems to inherits some of the parent activity styles (especially the accent color, but also edittext color).

Here is my activity theme :

```
<style name="Theme.MainMenu.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/myPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/myPrimary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/myAccent</item>
</style>
```

Here is how I create the AlertDialog (containing an EditText)

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert);
```

If I don't specify any theme to my activity, the AlertDialog display as expected :
[image: As expected]

But If I apply MyTheme to my activity, the AlertDialog looks like :
[image: Inherited colorAccent and EditText color]

Despite the **Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert** theme I give to the Builder. The accent color (here in red) and the EditText color seems to be inherited from the activity theme.

Why is there this inheritance, and how to avoid it, or, is there any solution to force the AlertDialog use the "full" default theme ?

Thanks a lot

**Edit 1 :**

As suggested by *MinnuKaAnae*, I can create a custom style for the DialogAlert, based on *Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert*, overriding needed attributes, but I need to point to AppCompat default colors :

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/NEED_APPCOMPAT_DEFAULT_COLOR_ACCENT_HERE</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/NEED_APPCOMPAT_DEFAULT_PRIMARY_COLOR_HERE</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/NEED_APPCOMPAT_DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR_HERE</item>
</style>
```

And in my case, I also need to override the EditText text color to the Light version (black text) because the Activity is not based on the Light theme : the attribute **android:editTextColor** doen't seem to do the job.

Comment: post your Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert

Comment: Create a custom theme and put in your's colorPrimary,colorDarkPrimary,and coloraccent  color and use it in this dialog

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae : The Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert style is the one of the Android Support Library.

Comment: @ND1010_ : Ok, I could create a custom theme for the AlertDialog, but I need to use the default (Theme.AppCompat.Light) colorPrimary/colorDarkPrimary and colorAccent. I thought a better solution may exist.

Comment: @Virtual this Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert will available in your styles.xml. You have to override colorAccent in order to achieve your need, try below answer. Add that in your styles.xml. That will work.

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">#006A4E</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#3f3f3f</item>
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Change

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
```

Comment: If if add this, I get a "_Duplicate symbol in table with resource type 'style' and symbol name 'Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert'_". As expected : Compat library defines this style name.

Comment: @Virtual style name AppCompatAlertDialogStyle can be anything, check my updated answer, parent name Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert, this is default theme in android, we have to override this.

Comment: or else change accent color in Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert  to your need.

Comment: Ok, If I use your suggestion, I need to know the **default AppTheme colorAccent** and also, be able to set the EditText text color, which attribute **android:editTextColor** doen't seem to do the job. See my post edit.

Comment: That the solution I'd like to avoid :) But thanks for your suggestions !

Answer (score 0):

If you want your AlertDialog to have a different theme that the one your Activity is using, try a context theme wrapper:

```
ContextThemeWrapper wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.CustomStyle);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(wrapper);
```